# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

How to resolve ambiguities in the **AUTOMATIC CONNECTION** of Bean in Spring?
We have a Dessert interface, and we have three different desserts (Beans) that implement the interface (Dessert).

The dessert of the day is Cookie, therefore we wrote it down as favorite with `@Primary`.

The problem is that the desserts have been made just and if someone wants to repeat dessert, there will be no more cookies, so we have created "repeatDessert" for those who want to repeat dessert.

In addition to the favorite dessert, there are two more desserts, CAKE AND ICECREAM.
 
We want everyone who repeats to be served IceCream dessert, of which we have enough.

How can we tell Spring which of the two desserts is it that we want it to serve?

```
public interface Dessert {
    void eat();
}
```

BEAN CAKE:

```
@Component
public class Cake implements Dessert{

    private Dessert repeatDessert;

    public Dessert getRepeatDessert() {
        return repeatDessert;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setRepeatDessert(Dessert repeatDessert) {
       this.repeatDessert = repeatDessert;
    }

    @Override
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Eating a Cake !!!!");
    }
}
```

BEAN COOKIE:

```
@Component
@Primary
public class Cookie implements Dessert{

    private Dessert repeatDessert;

    public Dessert getRepeatDessert() {
        return repeatDessert;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setRepeatDessert(Dessert repeatDessert) {
       this.repeatDessert = repeatDessert;
    }

    @Override
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Eating a Cookie !!!!");
    }
}
```

BEAN ICECREAM:

```
@Component
public class IceCream implements Dessert{

    private Dessert repeatDessert;

    public Dessert getRepeatDessert() {
        return repeatDessert;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setRepeatDessert(Dessert repeatDessert) {
       this.repeatDessert = repeatDessert;
    }

    @Override
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Eating a IceCream !!!!");
    }
}
```

This would be the configuration file:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class AutoBeanConfiguration {

}
```

This would be the Main class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.ERROR);
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctxt = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AutoBeanConfiguration.class);
        Cookies cookies = ctxt.getBean(Cookies.class);
        cookies.eat();
        Dessert dessert = cookies.getRepeatDessert();
        dessert.eat();
        ctxt.close();
    }

}
```

The program throws the following `exception`:

```
Exception in thread "main" Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cookies': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setRepeatDessert' parameter 0;
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'Dessert' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: cake,iceCream
```

How can we resolve the ambiguity and tell spring which of the Desserts do we want to create, when we want to repeat?

The console output should be this:

```
Eating a Cookies !!!!
Eating a IceCream !!!!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all , your code has compile error. Please change this code

```
Cookies cookies = ctxt.getBean(Cookies.class);
```

to

```
Cookie cookie = ctxt.getBean(Cookie.class);
```

And then in your bean class , all setter method has same name as repeatDessert. So this finds any repeatDessert beans same as this name. So this cannot find any bean with this.In your bean setter method of class;

```
@Autowired
public void setRepeatDessert(Dessert repeatDessert) {
   this.repeatDessert = repeatDessert;
}
```

Method parameter repeatDessert not specified to which beans. if you change all bean class like this with `Qualifier`.  [Read more detail about Qualifier](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html);

For `Cake.class`;

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("cake")
public void setRepeatDessert(Dessert repeatDessert) {
    this.repeatDessert = repeatDessert;
}
```

For `IceCream.class`;

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("iceCream")
public void setRepeatDessert(Dessert repeatDessert) {
    this.repeatDessert = repeatDessert;
}
```

For `Cake.class`;

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("cake")
public void setRepeatDessert(Dessert repeatDessert) {
    this.repeatDessert = repeatDessert;
}
```

Now your spring project works. But your result i think can not produce. Because you dont have any info about ice cream in your main, only you have `Cookie` but you wants to print `Eating a IceCream !!!!` . I didnt understand from your output. Can you provide if this cant help your problem ?

PS: If you want to change **repeatDessert** of your class, you can change with `@Qualifier("yourBeanName");` and you can provide the repeatable desert of anything.

Comment: ok, I wanted to always repeat the dessert, it was always ice cream. Your answer is correct. We can also create our own annotations as: @IceCream...